# c++ compile time array bounds checking not fully working in clang

Tags: c++, arrays, clang, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

I would like to check for compile time array bound violations, particulary for `std::array`. Unfortunately this check only works for bare standard arrays and not for any kind of wrapped array.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct Array{
    int data[2];

    int operator[](size_t i){
        return data[i];    
    }
};

int main() {
  int test1[]{1,2};
  std::cout << test1[2] << std::endl;

  std::array<int,2> test2{1,2};
  std::cout << test2[2] << std::endl;

  Array test3;
  std::cout << test3[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Output when using clang:

```
main.cpp:15:16: warning: Access out-of-bound array element (buffer overflow)

  std::cout << test1[2] << std::endl;

               ^~~~~~~~

main.cpp:15:16: note: Access out-of-bound array element (buffer overflow)

  std::cout << test1[2] << std::endl;

               ^~~~~~~~

1 warning generated.
```

The compile options are:
`clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ main.cpp -Weverything -Warray-bounds -Reverything --analyze -Xanalyzer -analyzer-output=text -Xanalyzer -analyzer-checker=alpha.security`

See coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c21f371f142ba51d

Is there a way to check for these errors too?

Comment: Did you enable the Optimizer? How did you compile?

Comment: The [`std::array::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_at) does not perform bounds checking. Use `at` instead.

Comment: @Ron `at` will only raise runtime exception, not even the most basic check at compile time.

Comment: @manni66 i used the compile options seen in coliru. i edited the post.

Comment: @Ron you are right, but im interested in compile time checks done by the compiler.

Comment: Do you think the compiler is that smart? Do you think it can solve the dead code problem?